# Dojo Dijit Calender widget disable all dates except for select few using isDisabledDate

Tags: javascript, date, calendar, dojo

I am having trouble understanding how to use the isDisabledDate property to disable all but a few dates.

The situation:

I am using the Dijit calender widget as part of a web app that allows control of a remote scheduler.

Basically, a list of jobs is retrieved from the server when a user requests. If there is a job scheduled for a particular particular date, that date should be enabled (otherwise disabled by default).

intuitively, in psudo-code, I want to do something like this:

```
function onGetJobsComplete(jobs){ 
    foreach(job in jobs) {
         dijit.byId('MyCalender').enableDate(job.date);
    }
}
```

The end result is, I would like the user to graphically see which days have jobs, and be able to click on these day to get additional information (this part i have working).

All the examples I can find seem to deal with blocking out dates based on a criteria that does not depend on external, changing data (ie: all weekends or some such)

edit:

I have attempted this:

```
     <div id="calSJobs" data-dojo-type="dijit/Calendar" data-dojo-props="
                dayWidth:'abbr',
                isDisabledDate: disabledDates"
                />
```

-

```
function disabledDates(value){
    if(typeof dataJobs == 'undefined')
        return true;
    try {   
    for(i=0; i<dataJobs.length; i++) {
        if(dataJobs[i].cron == 'False')
        {
                jobDate = new Date(dataJobs[i].time);
                calDate = value;
                if(compareDate(jobDate, calDate)
                    return false;
        }
    }
    } catch (err) {log(err.message);}
    return true;
}

var compareDate;
require(["dojo/date"], function(date){

compareDate = function (date1, date2) {
    if(date.compare(date1, date2, 'date') == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

});

But this has two problems:

- compareDate doesn't work because I am requiring AMD modules If I remove the "require" stuff, it works fine but then I can't use date.compare. This same sort of thing works elsewhere in my code but not when its being called by a dijit widget?
- How can I have the logic run when the data changes in addition to when the calender view changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create calendar as bellow, you can add logic which dates are enabled and which aren't

```
 new Calendar({
        value: new Date(),
        isDisabledDate: lang.hitch(this, function(d){
            return true;
        })
    }, "mycal");
```

This should disable all dates. Or if you want to enable some of them, you can add some logic to the function and return false in case that date is in your list.

Btw if you want to disable all dates inline, you can do as follows:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.Calendar" value="20120512" data-dojo-props="isDisabledDate:function(){return true; }"></div>
```

Comment: I'm really having trouble wrapping my head around the logic of dojo. I have written a function for the isDisabledDate, but I still have two problems:


-The time at which the calender refreshed its dates is still tied to the calender its self. (ie: disabled dates are calculated when you load the calender or flip through its pages). How do I refresh the disabled dates whenever I want, and not when the calender re-draws?

-I am having trouble using date.compare within the function. If i use any requires, the thing doesn't work. I'll edit the original to show this.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Disabled dates for Calendar is set once, when calendar is created, you can refresh them by calling _populateGrid() for the calendar widget, you can't enable single date. http://jsfiddle.net/BvwmL/